# AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

While cloudformation is building the stack, I get the following error:

AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   N1ClusterServerLaunchConfig    You are not authorized to perform this operation

I have admin full access user privileges. But, still this fails. Is the authorization due to the IAMs defined inside the template?

```
    "N1ClusterServerAutoScale": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": {
      "Fn::GetAZs": ""
    },
    "LaunchConfigurationName": {
      "Ref": "N1ClusterServerLaunchConfig"
    },
    "MinSize": "2",
    "MaxSize": "64",
    "DesiredCapacity": {
      "Ref": "ClusterSize"
    },
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
        },
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
      "id": "a715af00-ebba-4fab-a817-d5ee1986dfe7"
    }
  }
},
"N1ClusterServerLaunchConfig": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": {
      "Fn::FindInMap": [
        "RegionMap",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
        },
        "hvm"
      ]
    },
    "InstanceType": {
      "Ref": "InstanceType"
    },
    "KeyName": {
      "Ref": "KeyPair"
    },
    "SecurityGroups": [
      {
        "Ref": "N1ClusterSecurityGroup"
      },
      {
        "Ref": "N1NodeSecurityGroup"
      }
    ],
    "IamInstanceProfile": {
      "Ref": "IamInstanceProfile"
    },
```

IAM

```
   "AllowComputeFrom": {
      "Description": "The net block (CIDR) that N1-COMPUTE is available to.",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "IamInstanceProfile": {
      "Description": "The name of an IAM Profile which can access required S3 buckets and instances.",
      "Default": "arn:aws:iam::247256189695:instance-profile/n1-compute-instance",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "IamInstanceProfileShort": {
      "Description": "The last part of the name of an IAM Profile which can create instances.",
      "Default": "n1-compute-instance",
      "Type": "String"
    },
```

Comment: Share your IAM policies for your user or the user you are using with CF.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My account IAM permission is admin full access. The iam defined in the template is updated above.

Comment: Are you creating the IAM in the template.  There's a known issue with a timing/race condition that policies don't instantly attach to the Roles if both are defined in the template.

Answer (score 1):

While creating Autoscaling and Launchtemplate using boto3 and aws Lambda I received the same error. Adding following permissions to the Lambda role resolved the issue -

> iam:CreateInstanceProfile, iam:Passrole, iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole,
> iam:GetInstanceProfile, iam:ListInstanceProfile, iam:UpdateRole,
> iam:ListInstanceProfiles, iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile,
> iam:TagInstanceProfile,

[enter link description here](https://github.com/tathyalearner/common/blob/main/AWS_AutoScaling_LaunchConfiguration_not_authorized.json)
For people using cloudformation can add the same to it.

Answer (score 0):

ec2:RunInstances is required to use a Launch template

Comment: `iam:PassRole` is also a required permission if the ec2 instance has an IAM role.